# Команда для нахождения количества таблиц в бд postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Есть команда `\dt`, а можно как-то узнать, сколько всего таблиц, не выводя список?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Посчитает (с системными таблицами):**

```
SELECT COUNT(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','pg_catalog');
```

**Выдаст названия (с системными таблицами):**

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','pg_catalog');
```

**Посчитает в конкретных схемах:**

```
SELECT COUNT(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog') AND table_schema IN('schema_1', 'myschema');
```

--- далее можно написать

--- `OR table_schema IN('schema_2', 'myschema')`

...

--- `OR table_schema IN('schema_N', 'myschema')`